# Add More Mass action in Order grid in magento2

Tags: sales-order, magento2, order-grid, magento2-dev-beta

I want to create delete order functionality in magento2, but i am not able to add mass action in order grid. please help me how to create delete order functionality in magento2. Please help me if any one have idea.

Comment: Check this for add custom massaction in order grid: https://mageprince.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-mass-action-in-order-grid-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 18):

You need to define router for adminhtml in order to get it work with your custom module. You can define the same at 
app\code{{your_package}}{{your_module}}\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml as like below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="orderdelete" frontName="orderdelete">
            <module name="Krish_OrderDelete" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

You can define your own frontName for admin route. Now in your ui xml file, available at **view\adminhtml\ui_component** under custom mass action search the item name="url" and set path like "**orderdelete/order/massDelete**"

It should work if you will implement it correctly.

Please refer below module which I developed to add new MassDelete action in sales order grid (All the below files should be in your custom module i.e. **package_module**).

```
1. \etc\module.xml

    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Krish_OrderDelete" setup_version="1.0.0">
            <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            </sequence>
        </module>
    </config>

2. \etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="orderdelete" frontName="orderdelete">
            <module name="Krish_OrderDelete" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>

3. \view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
            <massaction name="listing_massaction">
                <action name="order_delete">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">order_delete</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="orderdelete/order/massDelete"/>
                            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Order(s)</item>
                                <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan\'t to delete selected items?</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </action>
            </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>

**Note: If you will define your action under tag <listingToolbar>, than new mass action will be added as child mass action.**

4. \Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassDelete.php

<?php

namespace Krish\OrderDelete\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;

/**
 * Class MassDelete
 */
class MassDelete extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractMassAction
{
    /**
     * @var OrderManagementInterface
     */
    protected $orderManagement;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $filter);
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
    }

    /**
     * Hold selected orders
     *
     * @param AbstractCollection $collection
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
    {
        $countDeleteOrder = 0;
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $order) {
            if (!$order->getEntityId()) {
                continue;
            }
            $loadedOrder = $model->load($order->getEntityId());
            $loadedOrder->delete();
            $countDeleteOrder++;
        }
        $countNonDeleteOrder = $collection->count() - $countDeleteOrder;

        if ($countNonDeleteOrder && $countDeleteOrder) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('%1 order(s) were not deleted.', $countNonDeleteOrder));
        } elseif ($countNonDeleteOrder) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('No order(s) were deleted.'));
        }

        if ($countDeleteOrder) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You have deleted %1 order(s).', $countDeleteOrder));
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath($this->getComponentRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}

5. \composer.json

{
    "name": "krish/magento2-order-delete",
    "description": "extension for deleting orders in magento 2",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Krish/OrderDelete"
            ]
        ]
    }
}


6. \registration.php

<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Krish_OrderDelete',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: Hmm Good Answer

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, how to add tree massactions, where multi dropdown like Assign then show all the users?

Comment: Nice answer, having all of the details. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Within your module you will want to create the following file: `view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

With the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
      <container name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="delete" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">sales/order/massDelete</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </massaction>
    </container>
  </listing>
```

Customise the URL path in `<item name="url" ..>sales/order/massDelete</item>` to your needs.

Take a look at `Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\MassCancel.php` for an example of how implement your controller!

Comment: Hello,  I am ablew to add the new mass action but my controller not working when i add in our module , if i put into "Magento/Sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order" then its working but when i add in our module then its not working . please help me how to add massaction function in our controller?

Comment: Do you have a `etc/adminhtml/routes.xml` file within your module? You can use a post I've written covering adminhtml as a reference: https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-part-5-adminhtml/

Comment: Hello Ash, how we can add dynamic mass action using above code

Comment: Use listingToolbar instead of container. working for me.

Answer (score -1):

Not "container" but "listingToolbar" in XML file, and everything works.