# Magento 2 : Add New Grid Mass Action based on condition

Tags: magento2, order-grid

I am working on one custom extension and need to add new mass action in Sales Order grid. 
But I need to add this mass action based on one condition.

I am working in Magento 2.1.1

How can I do this?

Any one have example then provide me.

Comment: You can refer Admin's any Module (Example: Catalog) with their Mass Action. You have to check Listing XML file & Controller file of that. Below are the links will help you out http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62177/how-to-add-a-mass-action-via-xml-in-magento-2 or http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97252/magento-2-add-a-mass-action-block-item or http://www.digital-pianism.com/en/blog/magento-1-vs-magento-2-how-to-add-massaction-item/. You try your self then if you found issue then please post your error happy to help

Comment: #Mike Smith Can you give me example with any specific options and explain it flow, Because in grid massactions is define in UI_Component. How can I implement that in my custom extension.

Comment: Please visit below link if it could help. it doesn't create conditionally, You can put your own condition while creating new mass action. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78861/add-more-mass-action-in-order-grid-in-magento2/132653#132653